# Sitecore Glass Mapper Installation Issue

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

After installing latest Glass Mapper I am seeing this issue: 
Could not load type 'Glass.Mapper.IDependencyResolver' from assembly 'Glass.Mapper, Version=4.2.1.188, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Sitecore Version : Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519)
Glass Mapper : Glass.Mapper.Sc

Yes before installation the project had references to Sitecore.Kernel and Sitecore.Mvc dlls.

Did anyone encounter this issue before?

Comment: When you are seeing this issue after installation and at the timing of running site or solution building error?

Comment: I am seeing this issue when running the site.... Solution builds and publishes successfully..

Comment: Are your Glass Mapper dll's published to the website?

Comment: I did some research on it and found that IDependencyResolver referenced in Glass.Mapper.Sc.IoC.IDependencyResolver  with the newer version and I think something is wrongly referenced do check files under app_start folder and check what reference they have.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh and Gatogordo for response...

Comment: @Vamshi thanks for posting an answer here I was also in same way that;s why I posted inj last comment thet something is wrongly referenced :)

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head finally I found out the reason... In the project there was an old glass mapper v3 or below was installed & uninstalled which didn't complete all the way through. It deleted all the references from the project but it didn't delete all the config files. It left glass.config in the app config folder and the include folder. After deleting these two files it started working as expected.